# How would a compiler turn an else-if cascade into a switch?

Tags: language-agnostic, compiler, efficiency

I don't like `switch` in C and its descendants. Maybe it's the need for a break or the clumsiness of the syntax requiring a shifting of mental gears, I don't know.

Whatever the reason, I will almost always write a sequence of else-if conditions examining the same variable rather than write a switch.

I see from [Is there any significant difference between using if/else and switch-case in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395618/439793) that switch is more efficient in most cases and it got me wondering...

How would a compiler (for a language with C-like `if`, `else` and `switch`) detect a number of else-if conditions on the same value and internally re-write it into a switch?

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat - I'm more interesting in reading up on existing practice than looking for a product recommendation.

Comment: "Are there any compilers" reads like asking to recommend a tool to me

Comment: I've added an edit clarifying.

Comment: You've got some really good answers below, but your starting position should also be reconsidered.  An `if`/`elseif`/.../`else` cascade has serious problem that a `switch` does not: The **source** code must be very carefully read to ensure that the mutual interations of all the conditions do not have strange impacts.  For example, side-effects of function calls, or simple typographic errors. This has nothing to do with compiler optimizations, and everything to do with readability and correctness.

Comment: @RossPatterson - If the value being else-if'd is a simple local variable, there's no problem. Typos may be a problem but the compiler will (!) report those errors and I avoid similarly named variables for reasons that go beyond else-if cascades.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your optimization wish (of transforming a sequence of `if` into the equivalent of a `switch`) makes sense only (as [Jörg W Mittag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1352/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag) wisely commented) for idempotent conditions (which are undecidable to detect in general). But we could restrict these conditions to be a disjunction of equality tests like *x* `==` *k* where *x* is always the same ([SSA-form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form)) *simple scalar variable* (e.g. some declared `int` local variable in C or C++) which is unmodified in *then* parts and *k* is a compile-time constant.

As far as I know, some versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) in some optimizations modes have been able of such an optimization. And I just checked (in march 2015), my *Clang 3.5* (invoked as `clang -O3 -fverbose-asm -S`) is doing such an optimization with the code below, while my *GCC 4.9* don't do it (on GNU/Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64) :

```
 extern void f_a(int);
 extern void f_b(int);
 extern void f_c(int);
 extern void f_d(int);
 extern void f_e(int);
 extern void f_f(int);
 extern void f_g(int);
 extern void f_h(int);
 extern void f_i(int);
 extern void f_j(int);
 extern void f_k(int);
 extern void f_l(int);
 extern void f_m(int);
 extern void f_n(int);

 void f1(int x, int y)
 {
   if (x=='a') f_a(y);
   else if (x=='b') f_b(y);
   else if (x=='c') f_c(y);
   else if (x=='d') f_d(y);
   else if (x=='e') f_e(y);
   else if (x=='f') f_f(y);
   else if (x=='g') f_g(y);
   else if (x=='h') f_h(y);
   else if (x=='i') f_i(y);
   else if (x=='j') f_j(y);
   else if (x=='k') f_k(y);
   else if (x=='l') f_l(y);
   else if (x=='m') f_m(y);
   else if (x=='n') f_n(y);
 }
```

<sup>I guess that *GCC* don't optimize like you want because it is not worth doing. GCC is often producing *slightly faster* code than Clang.</sup>

BTW, `switch` is not always compiled into an indirect jump. In particular a switch with a dozen of widely spread cases is *not* compiled using a jump table, e.g. code like

```
unsigned u = something(x); /// practically would be some hash function
switch (u) {
  case 3935272677: do_some_A(x); break;
  case 2389398680: do_some_B(x); break;
  case 1384792968: do_some_C(x); break;
  case 3957729125: do_some_D(x); break;
  case 4174747340: do_some_E(x); break;
  /// etc...
  default: do_other_thing(x); break;
}
```

<sup>In practice with `gcc -O3 -fverbose-asm -S` such code is compiled as a tree of branches.</sup>

You should read the paper by Roger Anthony Sayle *A Superoptimizer Analysis of Multiway Branch Code Generation* (GCC Summit 2008)

Also, `match` expressions in Ocaml are perhaps relevant, they are not always compiled as naive sequence of tests, but usually as a tree of tests.

There is a significant literature on compiling [**pattern matching**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching). See [Rete algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) for a start, and Luc Maranget & Fabrice Le Fessant [paper](http://gallium.inria.fr/~maranget/opt-pat.ps.gz) on *Optimizing Pattern Matching* (ICFP2001); you'll find a lot of papers and conferences on the subject.

BTW, your *implicit* hypothesis that some indirect branch is *always* faster than a serie of jumps is **naive** (on current processors), because of [TLB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer), [CPU caches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), [branch predictors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), [instruction pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline), conditional moves machine instructions, etc etc... Read also about [threaded code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code) and notice that both *GCC* and [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) accept the (very useful) [label as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) and *computed goto* extension to C.

Read also about GNU [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) perfect hash generator.

At last, you should not care and **leave such micro-optimizations to the compiler** ! If you feel (but I don't) that a long series of `if` is more readable than a long `switch` code as you prefer.

Comment: There is, of course, also the small matter that this optimization is only correct iff the condition is idempotent (and the not so small matter that deciding whether it is, is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem).

Comment: In an if .. else if .. else if chain, you only need to determine that evaluating any of the conditions has obviously no side effects, and then you check that each condition is comparing the identical variable against a constant.

Comment: In the example, the compiler could translate to switch (u % 16) { case 0: if (u == 3935272677) ... etc. } So instead of multiple comparisons, one switch and one comparison on average.

Comment: But I am not sure that would be faster, and I trust the compiler more than myself for such micro-optimizations.

Comment: `If you feel (but I don't) that a long series of if is more readable than a long switch code as you prefer.` In my opinion you should use whichever construct most closely matches the semantics of what you're trying to do. If that's "evaluate an expression and multibranch on the result", then use `switch`. I'd hope any objections are grounded in something more objective than "I don't like `<statement>`", or you'd validate truly insane requests like "I don't like `if/else`, I can just use a `while`." But I do agree that regardless of which you use, micro-optimizing that is the compiler's job. +1

Comment: @Doval - "micro-optimizing that is the compiler's job." - Exactly, that's why I'm surprised the answer to "Which is better, else-if or switch?" isn't an outright "The compiler generates the same output."